# Existence of independent components in degenerate normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\Sigma)$ for some $\mu\in\mathbb R^d$ and a symmetric, positive semidefinite $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{d,d}$, i.e. $\varphi_X(t)=\exp(it^T\mu-\frac12t^T\Sigma t)$ for every $t\in\mathbb R^d$.

Using the characteristic function I could easily show that for every $E\sim\mathcal N(0,I_d)$ and every $A\in\mathbb R^{d,d}$ satisfying $\Sigma=AA^T$ we have $X\sim AE+\mu$, but I could not prove that the components of $E$ are independent or that there is at least one $A\in\mathbb R^d$ and $E=(e_1,\dots,e_d)$ such that $e_1,\dots,e_d\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ are independent and $X\sim AE+\mu$ as [the second definition here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition) states.

Can you guys give me some hints or can you suggest some literature that might help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random variables with a joint normal distribution are independent iff their covariances are $0$.  Since $E(E_iE_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $E(E_i)=0$ for all $i$ it follows that the components $E_i$ are independent.

Comment: Ahh... Since $E\sim\mathcal N(0,I_d)$ is non-degenerate, it actually has a probability density and from the marginal probability density we get $E(E_iE_j)\neq0$ for $i\neq j$, right?